# Ejb sql [select * from where A & 1]

Tags: java, sql, mysql, ejb

I will use a query like this in ejb ql:

```
Select * from whe A&1;
```

But I have the following error:

```
line 1, column 171: unexpected char [&].
```

How can I use this operator to check the bits in a row?

Answer (score 1):

use [BIT_AND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-and) function

Comment: the check also the if function